# Stack Exchange Icon on IOS

Tags: support, status-norepro

So I'm super sad; the server fault icon has gone from my home screen!

[image: SuperSad!]

Make it come back?

Comment: Wait... we have an app? Or is that a bookmark and someone is mucking about with our favicon?

Comment: @voretaq7 - bookmark icon. There was an unofficial app called 6to8 but it was unmaintained, and was read only (due to the API). Since the mobile site, it's totally unnessesary

Comment: I wonder if SF was having one of its little maintenance outages when the bookmark icon was last checked?  I vaguely believe the generic error page has the more generic icon.

Answer (score 3):

Never mind, it came back when I re-opened the site. Must have been a glitch in the matrix.

Comment: There's probably an app for that.